# Apply border to UIBarButtonItem in ios7

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, xcode5, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have seen UIBarButtonItem,UIButtons are borderless in ios7.But I want to have the appearance of UIBarButtonItem like in <=ios6.At the same time I cannot apply a particular backgroundimage because navigationbar tint colour changes from some set of views to other views.
How can I set borderstyle in `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`  may be by using some `CALayer` properties or so ..?

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to build your `UIBarButtonItem` from a `UIButton` with rounded corners.

Comment: But I want don't want to set it for every view.I want to take it globally in AppDelegate and use it in some set of views.How can I do it?

Comment: My understanding is that you CAN'T, as `UIBarButton` isn't a view, but a proxy object user by iOS to draw its buttons - and the 'style'  `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` doesn't seem to have any effect since iOS 7